# Error creating bean with name 'statelessInvalidateTokenFilter

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to use Grails Spring Security Stateless Plugin but I am getting below exception. I have done exactly same as documentation but I am unable to start the application.

Grails version 2.4.4
jdk1.7.0_79

```
Configuring Spring Security Stateless ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Stateless
| Error 2017-02-24 12:24:36,402 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'statelessInvalidateTokenFilter': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'endpointUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'endpointUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
Message: Error creating bean with name 'statelessInvalidateTokenFilter': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'endpointUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'endpointUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'endpointUrl'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'endpointUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [groovy.util.ConfigObject] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'endpointUrl': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/security244
```

Comment: Failed to convert property value of type 'groovy.util.ConfigObject' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'endpointUrl'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config property was not named correctly. Check the exact name and then define it in `application.groovy/.yml` file. The issue was of plugin as plugin do not define any default value so if property was not defined in `application.groovy` it throws this exception

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing these properties:

```
grails.plugin.security.stateless.springsecurity.invalidate.active=false
grails.plugin.security.stateless.springsecurity.invalidate.endpointUrl="/stateless/yourinvalidateurl"
```

Add these to Config.groovy and it should work